# Как отобрать элементы, которые имеют вложенные элементы с определенным классом?

Tags: jquery

Как, например, отобрать элементы такого вида на странице:

```
<a href="#"><span class="icon"><span>Sometext</a>
```

т.е. надо выбрать все элементы а, содержащие внутри себя элемент span с классом info?

Comment: у вас что-то с хтмл разметкой, тэг a закрывается раньше чем вложенные в него span'ы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a:has(span.info)');
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('a .icon').html());
```

Comment: Нет, это не то. Так отберутся элементы с классом icon, вложенные в элементы а.